Update single view with two observers with Firebase Realtime database and SwiftUI
I want to see if this is possible as I am not sure how to achieve this, at least for both parts.
I have two nodes in Firebase Realtime database:
One is a node with the GroupID and all the UserId associated to the good with a boolean to determine if active or not:
Groups:
------- GroupID:
        -------- UserID : True/False

the other is a Node for UserNotes:
Notes:
------ GroupID:
       -------- UserID: 
                ------- Paid: True/False

What I would like to do is the following:
Observe BOTH nodes for any changes to see if the Group owner changes their status to Active/Inactive in the first node
AND/OR
Also monitor if the group owner changes their paid status to Paid/Unpaid.
I have the following code which works for the Active/Inactive function:
self.groupRef.child(groupId).observe(.value, with: { (snap) in
        
    self.user = []
        
    var counter: UInt = 0
        
    for child in snap.children {

            let userId = (child as! DataSnapshot).key
            
            self.userNotesRef.child(groupId).child(userId).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

                let val = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
                
                let note = val?["Note"] as? String ?? ""
                let paid = val?["Paid"] as? Bool ?? false
                
                print("USERS Paid: ", paid)
                print("USERS Note ", note)
            
            })

     }

})

In the above the first observer checks for changes to the groupRef.child(groupId).observe(.value and will update the list view with the change toggling to Active/Inactive
While the second observer userNotesRef.child(groupId).child(userId).observe(.value doesn't seem to update the view at all even tho the group owner is toggling the users Paid/Unpaid status!?
Can someone suggest how to get this to work and update both all in one List view in SwiftUI?

Because the second observation is inside the first, you will only set up the second observer when the first value changes. You need to create both observers at the same level. Your problem then may be that you need to observe all user IDs. You may well need to reconsider your database structure.

That is gonna suck... but im thinking my use case is common.
